# Redirect 301 for URLs with same parameter, different values, different targets

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This mod_rewrite works for one URL - /blog/ - I have to target:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pagenumber=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/? [R=301,L]
```

The issue I have is that `pagenumber` can be 2, 3, 4, and so on for a number of different query URLs, such as:

```
/blog?pagenumber=2
/blog?pagenumber=3
/blog?pagenumber=4

/corp?pagenumber=2
/corp?pagenumber=3

/new-1?pagenumber=2
```

Is it possible to create a RewriteCond such as:

```
^/blog(^\?)pagenumber=([0-9]*)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/?
```

that I can reuse for each individual URL  (/blog/, /corp/, etc.)?

(I'm certain that example is not right, but wanted to get the idea across...)

Or is there another, simpler way that I am missing?

Any help that anyone can provide would be most appreciated.

Thank you!

Bryan

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to requested path without query perameter, Replace your Rule with the following

```
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 

As such:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pagenumber=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]

this causes URL redirect to domain.com/index.php.